# Need to help query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a question about SQL Server.

Table: `patient`

```
pn | hospid | doj
------------------------
1  |   10   | 2015-10-14
1  |   10   | 2015-05-14
1  |   10   | 2015-08-12
```

2nd table: `patientrefs`

```
sdate      | edate      | codes | descripton  | pn | hospid
-------------------------------------------------------------
2015-01-01 | 2015-09-30 |  500  | active      |  1 | 10
2015-01-01 | 2015-09-30 |  501  | inactive    |  1 | 10
2015-10-01 | 2016-03-31 |  500  | activestill |  1 | 10
2015-10-01 | 2016-03-31 |  501  | inactive    |  1 | 10
2013-03-09 | 2013-09-12 |  300  | inactive    |  1 | 10
```

Both table common columns `pn + hospid` and patient tables related dos between sdate and edate of patientrefs table.

And in patientrefs table descritpton=inactive and date between condition satisfy then codes we consider inactivecodes

In patientrefs table descritpton<>inactive and date between condition satisfy then codes we consider activecodes

Based on this above table I want output like this:

```
pn|hospid|doj        |inactivecodes| activecodes
------------------------------------------------
1 |10    |2015-05-14 |  501        |  500
1 |10    |2015-08-12 |  501        |  500 
1 |10    |2015-10-14 |  501        |  500
```

I tried like this:

```
select  
    a.pn, a.hospid, a.doj,
    case when b.descripton <> 'inactive' then b.codes end activecodes,
    case when b.descripton = 'inactive' then b.codes end inactivecodes 
from 
    patient a 
left join 
    patientrefs b on a.pn = b.pn and a.hospid = b.hospid
                  and a.doj between b.sdate and b.edate
```

But that query is not returning the expected result.

And I tried another way

```
select  
    a.pn, a.hospid, a.doj, b.codes as inactivecodes
from 
    patient a 
left join 
    patientrefs b on a.pn = b.pn and a.hospid = b.hospid
                  and a.doj between b.sdate and b.edate
where 
    b.descripton = 'inactive'

select   
    a.pn, a.hospid, a.doj, b.codes as activecode
from 
    patient a 
left 
    patientrefs b on a.pn = b.pn and a.hospid = b.hospid
                  and a.doj between b.sdate and b.edate
where 
    b.descripton <> 'inactive'
```

Here the individual queries return the expected result, but I need active and inactivecodes in the above expected output format.

Please tell me how to write query to get my expected result in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    p.pn,
    p.hospid,
    p.doj,
    inactivecodes   = MAX(CASE WHEN pr.description = 'inactive' THEN pr.codes END),
    activecodes     = MAX(CASE WHEN pr.description = 'active' THEN pr.codes END)
FROM patient p
LEFT JOIN patientrefs pr
    ON p.pn = pr.pn
    AND p.hospid = pr.hospid
    AND p.doj BETWEEN pr.sdate AND pr.edate
GROUP BY
    p.pn, p.hospid, p.doj
```